# Set position of loading icon

Tags: html, css, background-image, alt

I am trying to set a icon when the image is loading. My problem is that I don't know how set the position of the icon. If you see the example the icon will be show over the alt attribute.

Demo:

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="www.google.pt">
<img class="industry_img" src="" title="xpto" alt="alt"/>
</a>
<hr>
<a class="thumbnail" href="www.google.pt">
<img class="industry_img" src="smiley.gif" title="xpto" alt="alt"/>
</a>

.industry_img {
    background-image: url("loader.gif");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3znz2ajg/

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set `padding-top` on the `img`

If you like you could also add some negative top margin to counter the top padding.

```
.industry_img {
    background-image: url("http://www.maravilhalivros.com.br/skin/frontend/mtherla/default/images/loader.gif");
    background-position: center center;
    border: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top:60px; /* added */
    margin-top: -25px; /* added */
}
```

### [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3znz2ajg/3/)

Comment: that is just an example to show the problem. I have scr always defined

Comment: If you have a src defined, then you shouldn't see the alt text! - in which case I don't see the problem which you describe occurring

Comment: I see the alt attr before when loading the image, where the icon must be visible too. The problem is just visual. I want the icon below or after the alt.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand what you mean looking the jsfidle. the problem is easy to understand. Just a preload icon without overlay the text of alt.

Comment: By adding top padding the alt text will appear under the icon

Answer (score 0):

No way you can change the alt maybe byy adding text-indent but i don't think that is what you want. You can do this though

```
<div class="load" style="width:200px;height:200px">
    <img src="large.jpg" alt="alternate text" />
</div>

.load{background:url('http://www.maravilhalivros.com.br/skin/frontend/mtherla/default/images/loader.gif') no-repeat center;}
```